# Determine different DateTime formats and convert them to one format

Tags: php, datetime, format

I have different DateTime formats and need to convert them to a standardized format.

Is there any build in PHP method which accepts different formats and returning them as a DateTime object or something else easy to format? I searched php.net and also this forum but can't find anything.

Just want to save time before I start coding something which probably already exists.

my formats to catch:

```
d.m.Y
d/m/Y
d-m-Y

m.d.Y
m/d/Y
m-d-Y

Y.d.m
Y/d/m
Y-d-m

Y.m.d
Y/m/d
Y-m-d
```

If there is no PHP method I will write my own class or if someone has something handy to share... :)

Thanks!

Comment: Answer please what date it is: `05/01/2011`? You cannot guess right with both `m/d/Y` and `d/m/Y` expected formats

Comment: yeah your right. Didn't saw this problem coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and your formats in a loop and check if valid object has been created

Comment: omg.. I tried it with createFromFormat but it always return false... but my failure was that I misunderstood the method. $format checks the $time and return false if the input time is not in that format.. Thanks dude open my eyes :)